# Powerpoint VBA - Set DataRange for DataLabels

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have no idea how to set DataRange for DataLabels using VBA.
Powerpoint does not have recording capabilities as well.

**Can anybody tell me to do this using VBA please?**
[image]

Comment: FYI, the documentation in MSDN for this was very tricky.  However, after looking through it and submitting an incomplete answer, I finally thought to use the recorder in Excel and then modify it for PowerPoint, which is where I found the final solution.  Worth knowing in case you have other similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The code to accomplish this is as follows:

```
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim mySerCol As SeriesCollection
Dim strRange As String

strRange = "=Sheet1!$F$2:$F$5" 'To hold the range for the new labels

Set myChart = ....[put in code to get the appropriate chart]
Set mySerCol = myChart.SeriesCollection(i)
mySerCol.ApplyDataLabels 'Turn on the datalabels for this series

'The next line sets the range to get the values from
mySerCol.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange _
               , strRange, 0
mySerCol.ShowRange = True 'Show the values from the range
mySerCol.ShowValue = False 'Do not show the actual values of the points
```

Note that this will only do this for one of the series.  To do the other ones, loop through i in the myChart.SeriesCollections(i) line.

Comment: Seems to be a great answer. I will try this in couple of hours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

****EDIT**** See other answer.  I am leaving this here because it provides some information about several objects that could be used, but doesn't actually solve the problem.

This is not a complete answer to the issue, but this is too long for a comment.

I've searched through the documentation for the Datalabels and was unable to figure out how to do this (I assume that you want to be able to define the range that the labels come from using VBA).  I was able to "check" the checkbox, but couldn't figure out where the range that is attached to it is.  The appropriate code to check.

To check the checkbox, use this code:

```
 myChart.SeriesCollection(i).ApplyDataLabels
```

where i is the series in question and myChart is a Chart object referencing your chart.  There are a bunch of parameters to this method that will allow you to show different items (percentages, values, etc.), but none of the parameters is a range.

This defaults to the values of the series if you do not enter any of the optional parameters

It is then possible to turn this on and off using:

```
myChart.SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.ShowRange = True/False
```

It is possible to change the caption of the Datalabels using:

```
myChart.SeriesCollection(i).DataLabels(j).Caption = "MY CAPTION"
```

This will change the caption one at a time, and it will replace the value that the "ApplyDataLabels" method puts in there.  It would be possible to loop through the range to set the values, but this is likely not what you are looking for.

There's also this:

```
myChart.SeriesCollection(i).HasDataLabels = True
```

but this just seems to turn them on and off and resets the captions that you may have put in there.

MSDN link uses both the hasdatalabels property and the applydatalabels method, but it is not clear why they are using both: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff745965.aspx

Hopefully this can at least give you something to start with.

Comment: Ok I will try the 2nd answer. Thanks